# How to subclass another class with generic in Swift?

Tags: generics, swift

My protocols and classes are:

```
protocol Named {

}

class A<T: Named> {

}
```

And now I want to create a class inherents from P:

```
class B: A {

}
```

But a compile error occupy, it says:

`Reference to generic type 'A' requires arguments in <...>`

Please tell me how can I subclass another class with generic, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple example.

```
protocol Named{
  var firstName:String {get set}
  var lastName: String {get set}

  var fullName: String{ get }

  }

class Person: Named{

  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String

  var fullName: String{
  return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
  }

  init(firstName: String, lastName: String){
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
  }

}

class A<T: Named>{
  var named: T

  init(named: T){
    self.named = named
  }
}




class B: A<Person> {
  init(){
    let person = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Appleseed")
    person.fullName
    super.init(named: person)
  }
}
```

Note that when you subclass from a generic class, you have to have the subclass as the generic as well, and the super class must be passed the same generic variable used in subclass. It also seems like explicit typecasting is necessary to denote the generics (protocol in our case), see initializer in class B. Initializing subclass also requires the explicit generic type to be passed while initializing as B(). This is my own experiment. There could be easy and more succinct ways to do this.

#### Update Swift 5.7

With Swift 5.7, you can handle this with `some` and `any` which provides much better syntax.

```
protocol Named {
  var firstName:String { get set }
  var lastName: String { get set }

  var fullName: String { get }

  }

class Person: Named{

  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String

  var fullName: String{
  return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
  }

  init(firstName: String, lastName: String){
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
  }

}

class A {
  var named: any Named

  init(named: some Named) {
    self.named = named
  }
}




class B: A {

  init() {
    let person = Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Appleseed")
    person.fullName
    super.init(named: person )
  }

}
```

Comment: Another question:

If I have another protocol named `protocol Aged {}`，and class A is: `class A<T: Named, Aged> {}`, now class B I write `class B<M: Named, Aged>: A<M> {}`，but a compile error occupy again

Comment: You can use `protocol<Named,Aged>` to combine the requirements.